# Why there is a exception while editing the user details?

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am sending the user-edited details from the angular app. In Edit form, I am allowing the user to edit only a few fields rest remail the same as previous. In this method, I am assigning the previous non changed values to the object with edited values.

```
  public async Task<IActionResult> PutUsers(int id,[FromForm] Users users)
        {
            var user = _context.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Email == users.Email);
            if (id != users.Id)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }
            users.Password = user.Password;
            users.UserImageGuid = user.UserImageGuid;
            users.UserImageName = user.UserImageName;
            users.DOB = user.DOB;
            

            try
            {
                _context.Entry(users).State = EntityState.Modified;
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                if (!UsersExists(id))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }

            return NoContent();
        }
```

here I am having the exception "The instance of entity type 'Users' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the conflicting key values."
Please help me out.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that you are trying to save one entity which has primary key same as the entity that you got from the database (in this case user and users objects).
There are several ways for you to fix this, simplest would be to simply detach users object from context before saving:

```
_context.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Detached;
```

You can also retrieve users object unattached (in which case you don't have to set State to Detached later):

```
var user = _context.Users.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Email == users.Email);
```

Other one would be to update user with data from users and just save changes.

Comment: Tracking changes has its benefits, it helps avoid concurrency

Comment: @Nemanja Now there no exception, but data is not getting saved inside the database.

Comment: @Akash which variant did you use? If you are saving user that you got from the database, you need to mark it as modified.

Answer (score 1):

You got the same entity tracked twich.
One "user" come from `_context.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Email == users.Email);`
The other "users" from `_context.Entry(users).State = EntityState.Modified;`

You cannot have the same entity tracked multiple time on same context.

Just use `=> _context.Users.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Email == users.Email);` or change the user attribute and avoid `_context.Entry(users).State = EntityState.Modified;`